How does FontBook select the default font to display in the preview when selecting a typeface?
For example, I've selected "SF Pro Text", the top level "Typeface Family" and it shows light font variant in the display.
In other fonts, it shows italics. It seens very random. I am developing a typeface and I want to make sure the "Regular" font is displayed to the customers.


How many styles and weights are you planning? I suspect there's nothing you can do to influence which font FB selects.
